# Download Image with URL or Private (ASW S3) URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Normally, Downloading an image with its URL in HTML itself we can do like this

```
<a href="path-to-image.jpg" download>
  <img src="path-to-image.jpg" />
</a>
```

for the same thing to achieve via javascript we can use like

```
const a = document.createElement('a')
      a.href = 'image-url'
      a.download = 'image-name.jpg'
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a)
```

Both are working fine for data:image format. 
If I click/run, Image will be download in my system for me

But If I use an image URL like 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcThv9yU8CfslQC7f7B5UkZyK-ZNMjdgXsgOxYgh8tdgsqwMBppx&usqp=CAU' or 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/09f/fff.png' are redirect to image page and displaying the image.

It should be download directly instead of displaying as a new tab.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/Danielprabhakaran_N/54v7hfe1/25/

Help me with this guys. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> a [download] can no longer download resources from a different origin.
>   it will work with same origin

Please find this [link](https://medium.com/charisol-community/downloading-resources-in-html5-a-download-may-not-work-as-expected-bf63546e2baa) usefull to download othersite images